# How to measure position of UI objects on iPhone simulator screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview, keyboard, ios-simulator, uisearchbar

I have calculated positions and offsets on paper. I have written code and debugged that I get expected results. However **on iPhone Simulator things are overlapping** by about 15 pixels.

To go on with my debugging, I need to know where exactly UI objects are on the screen.

Related to popup search keyboard and resizing a UITableView between static UISearchBar and dynamically added UITabBar (table view is embedded into one of the tabs). No, I really **don't want to use any hardcoded values** due rotation and different screen sizes.

How can I find out this?

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
if (self.keyboardShown)
    return;

// Get keyboard dimensions
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
CGSize kbSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;
NSValue* endValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey];
CGPoint endCenter = [endValue CGPointValue];

CGRect frame = myView.frame;
frame.size.height = endCenter.y - kbSize.height/2 - frame.origin.y;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

myView.frame = frame;

[UIView commitAnimations];

self.keyboardShown = YES;
}
```

...code just in case there're obvious bugs I can't see anymore...

Comment: Sorry, found answer to the code part: http://gargantuchet.blogspot.com/2009/12/i-came-across-post-updating-uiview-to.html BUT STILL would like to know how to know exact location of UI objects on simulator screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably UIView's `convertPoint:toView:`. To find out where a given view is located, use:

```
CGPoint myPoint = [myView convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toView:((YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window];
```

Comment: Great tip, much better than I was looking for!